# Using IOS Entitlements for NSFileProtectionComplete Encryption

Tags: ios, security, encryption, entitlements

IOS:  6.1
IDE:  Appcelerator Titanium 3.0

I am using IOS Entitlements to supposedly set app contents as encrypted when the device is passcode locked.

We have a developer profile with this entitlement setting:
com.apple.developer.default-data-protection
    NSFileProtectionComplete

and I also add this row/key set to the Entitlements.plist file for my app.

This is an html-based app that includes a lot of html text content and images, as well as use of sqlite databases.  When I set the above and deploy the app, passcode lock the device, hook it up to a separate computer not synced with iTunes for this device, and then browse the device via iExplore, I can verify that I can no longer access the database files, which were stored in the 'Private Documents' by the device.  BUT, I can still access and save my html files (with all the text content) and images/audio/etc. from within iExplore.  This is sensitive data functioning without network access, so serving up the data securely is not an option.

Why does it not also encrypt the other resources?   Is there any other way other than trying to create a Titanium module to set the NSFileProtectionKey attribute on EACH individual resource within the app (which didn't work when I first tried this)?

Comment: Do you mean [Apple's iOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOS) or [Cisco's IOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cisco_IOS)?  Your questions says IOS (which is Cisco) but seems to be referring to iOS (which is Apple).  Notice the difference is in the case of the leading "I"

Comment: I meant Apple iOS.  I found the problem was the app bundle resources are READ ONLY.  So it doesn't encrypt the other resources like it does the database, which is stored outside the app bundle in 'Private Documents'

Comment: Awesome!  Good find.  You may wish to answer your own question with your solution.